# MSAL Issue when using login Pop up in .net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I have an issue on azure AD authenticate, I want to make a social sign up form and implement the popup login on that, but when the user success login with social login the popup not close and the callback on the page not execute.

Popup view is a blank view

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

when it run only have html head and body

the msal script for execute popup

```
 $('.google.btn').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $.bta.showSpinner();
                    sessionStorage.clear();
                    var redirectUrl = '@HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Url.Action("SocialSignUpPage", "Account")))';

                    msalConfig.auth.redirectUri = redirectUrl;
                    const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

                    myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest)
                        .then((response) => {
                            console.log(response)
                            handleAzureResponse(response)
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            $.bta.hideSpinner();
                            if (error.errorCode !== 'user_cancelled') {
                                $.bta.showErrorDialog(error.errorMessage);
                            }
                        });
                });
```

Do anyone know why the popup didn't close and the handleAzureResponse(response) not executed?

Thankyou

Edit: the popup link when stuck `https://localhost:44340/Account/SocialSignUpPage#state=eyJpZCI6Im....`

Edit 06/02/2023
When I Close the popup, an error appear on my console in app

```
[c6fd4255-4106-4852-86c1-d0fe60b2ce7f] : msal.js.browser@2.32.2 : Error - PopupHandler.monitorPopupForHash - window closed
```

Comment: Have you checked the console in the browser to see if any client-side (javascript) errors occurred?  This would be the first thing I would check.

Comment: The following issue is very similar to what you are describing and is fairly recent: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5091 -- although the reports all seem to indicate that when the problem occurs for them the "popup link" finishes with NO HASH shown on the end.  The "popup link when stuck" that you pasted, still shows the hash.  :(

Comment: sure, I have check the console from the popup it's not generate any error, but in my app I have an error of google tag manager